# Find and replace all URL'S that is between [link] and [/link] with hyperlinks

Tags: php, url, replace, hyperlink

I'm having trouble making or finding a script that turns

```
[link]https://google.com[/link]
```

into

```
<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>
```

and so on.
I have tried these things...

```
$message = str_replace("[link]", "<a href=\"", $message);
$message = str_replace("[/link]", "\" target=\"_blank\">LINK</a>", $message);


preg_match('@((https?://)?([-\\w]+\\.[-\\w\\.]+)+\\w(:\\d+)?(/([-\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)*)@', $message, $url);

foreach($url as $link){
  $between = get_string_between($fullstring, '[link]', '[/link]');
  $message = str_replace("[link]", "<a href=\"", $message);
  $message = str_replace("[/link]", "\" target=\"_blank\">$between</a>", $message);
}


function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
   $string = ' ' . $string;
   $ini = strpos($string, $start);
   if ($ini == 0) return '';
   $ini += strlen($start);
   $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
   return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

preg_match('@((https?://)?([-\\w]+\\.[-\\w\\.]+)+\\w(:\\d+)?(/([-\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)*)@', $message, $url);

foreach($url as $link){
  $message = str_replace("[link]", "<a href=\"", $message);
  $message = str_replace("[/link]", "\" target=\"_blank\">LINK</a>", $message);
}
```

But the error is that the output is not

```
<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>
```

but

```
<a href="https://google.com">LINK</a>
```

or just the same $between variable everytime

```
<a href="https://gyazo.com/f8df70551ddf79c5f5a841b904324db7">https://gyazo.com/f8df70551ddf79c5f5a841b904324db7</a>
<a href="https://google.com">https://gyazo.com/f8df70551ddf79c5f5a841b904324db7</a>
```

and the code I have tried with preg_match() gets alot of random stuff.

```
Array(
  [0] => https://gyazo.com/f8df70551ddf79c5f5a841b904324db7
  [1] => https://gyazo.com/f8df70551ddf79c5f5a841b904324db7
  [2] => https://
  [3] => gyazo.co
  [4] => 
  [5] => /f8df70551ddf79c5f5a841b904324db7
  [6] => f8df70551ddf79c5f5a841b904324db7
)
```

And yes i have tried some other filters then whats described here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function PregGet( $text, $regex ) {
    preg_match_all( $regex, $text, $matches );

    return $matches[2];
}

function PregReplace( $text, $regex, $replace ) {
    return preg_replace( $regex, $replace, $text );
}

$text    = '[link]https://google.com[/link] <br>[link]https://yahoo.com[/link]';
$matches = PregGet( $text, '(\[(link)\](.*?)\[\/(link)\])' );
foreach ( $matches as $match ) {
    $a = str_replace('[link]', '', str_replace('[/link]', '', $match))
    $text = PregReplace( $text, '(\[(link)\](' . $a . ')\[/(link)\])', '<a href="' . $a . '">' . $a . '</a>' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove "[link]" and "[/link]", and after that, take the actual url and build the link:

```
<?php

$links = array(
    '[link]https://google.com[/link]',
    '[link]https://gyazo.com/f8df70551ddf79c5f5a841b904324db7[/link]'
);

foreach ($links as $link){
    $link = str_replace('[link]', '', $link);
    $link = str_replace('[/link]', '', $link);
    $message = '<a href="'. $link . '">' . $link . '</a>';

    echo $message . "\n";
}
```

This outputs:

```
<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>
<a href="https://gyazo.com/f8df70551ddf79c5f5a841b904324db7">https://gyazo.com/f8df70551ddf79c5f5a841b904324db7</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could just find the string in between the **[link][/link]** block. See this.

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$message = "[link]https://google.com[/link]";
$url = get_string_between($message, '[link]', '[/link]');
$message = str_replace("[link]", "<a href=\"", $message);
$message = str_replace("[/link]", "\" target=\"_blank\">".$url."</a>", $message);

echo $message
```

Hope this helps you out.